# Importing downloaded .apk to Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

You download an .apk file (ex. Radio Disney app) and you want to import it to Android Studio. How could you be able to do that? Explain.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can decompile the `.apk` using [this decompiler](http://www.decompileandroid.com/) or [another one](http://www.javadecompilers.com/apk) to decompile the apk and download sources, those can be imported in android studio.

The first compiler's results look the easiest to be imported into android studio.
I'm going to try this in a couple of hours so i may improve my answer over time.

Comment: I found the 2nd one worked better. The first one stalled in the first try. Then it had a gateway timeout in the 2nd try.

Comment: ya, right, also, first one is now not working in chrome, because, chrome is now not supported flash.

Comment: @ShurvirMori Yes, Chrome does not support flash anymore, this is why to use flash you need to use a different browser, like [Mozilla Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/)

Answer (score 2):

Android Studio 3.0.1 (at the time of writing this answer) has a built in function to import an apk file.[image]

This is what it looks like after you click on the import apk button.

Comment: This solution only creats .smali files but not .java files